# how to refer to jar inside ear in classpath

Tags: jar, classpath

How can I do refer to a jar inside ear in my classpath

I tired

```
javac Main.java -classpath myear.ear/common.jar
```

and

```
javac Main.java -classpath myear.ear!/common.jar
```

but didn't work

Thanks

Comment: do you mean compiling a source file packaged in an archive???

Comment: Not. Just a normal java class that refers to a jar inside ear